# Is there way to loop in NiFi expression language to add padding to the data?

Tags: apache-nifi

There is a date field in the record. That is in the format below "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.sss"(using this date value as a string). In some records, the milliseconds are rounded off from the source for example

1. 2018-05-15 15:30:20.123
2. 2018-05-15 15:30:20.12
3. 2018-05-15 15:30:20.3

Is there a way to pad the additional zeros in example 2 and 3 like below in NiFi?

2. 2018-05-15 15:30:20.120
3. 2018-05-15 15:30:20.300

Is there way to loop in NiFi expression language?

PS: Right now I am using three different processors to do this loop by having the date as an attribute and check its length as a condition and decide to add '0' if needed. And another approach I tried is using an Execute script processor. But trying to find if there is a **better solution to this?**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assume you have attribute `date = 2018-05-15 15:30:20.3`

you can use updateattribute with expression like this:

```groovy
${date:append('000'):replaceAll('(\\.\\d{3})(.*)$','$1')}
```

append extra zeros and then remove the needless with regexp replace